# Is it possible to bind a checkbox value to a complex type in a Minimal API

Tags: c#, .net-8.0, minimal-apis

The offical documentation suggests it is possible to bind the `IsCompleted` property of a Todo class as described below using form binding (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#bind-to-collections-and-complex-types-from-forms)

```cs
class Todo
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; } = false;
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
}
```

The result is `BadHttpRequestException: The value 'on' is not valid for 'IsCompleted'.`

I have used the exact code referenced and I suspect the documentation is wrong.

(An addition of `app.UseAntiforgery();` is required.)

Before submitting a bug report on the documentation I would like to have this verified by others.

Comment: Am I missing something? If `"on"` should be valid, then where is the `TryParse` method in your example?

Comment: @Silvermind checkbox binding is supported in the controllers out of the box AFAIK. So one might expect the same in minimal APIs (or might not =).

Comment: The sample is not mine, it is from the official documentation which imho should work...

Answer (score 0):

See the [Checkbox binding](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-form-binding-in-minimal-apis/#checkbox-binding) section of the linked in the docs "Form binding in minimal APIs" article by Andrew Lock. Basically it is not supported in minimal APIs ATM:

> The interesting question for me here is: what should happen? Should minimal APIs "special-case" binding bool to the string `"on"` when the `[FromForm]` attribute is applied? How should it handle the fact the value is expected not to be there?

> On the one hand you can certainly work around these limitations yourself with custom types and default values, but that feels like a lot of effort considering how fundamental checkboxes are. On the other hand, building in "workarounds" into minimal APIs doesn't sound great either, as it introduces inconsistencies and increases overall complexity.

You can consider defining property as string and doing something like the following:

```
public class ToDoModel
{
    // ...

    public string? isCompleted { get; set; }

    public bool isCompletedBool => "on".Equals(isCompleted, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Notes.

1. I would consider using controllers for form binding since they have much richer support and more time-tested behaviour.
2. If you will post form only with default values it will actually bind it as `null` based on my tests, so beware of this behaviour too.

Comment: I have been reading the post by Andrew but since the official docs says it should work I wanted to see if anyone had feedback on why the example by Microsoft doesn't work.